# Замена строки в JS

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как при помощи регулярки удалить хэш символ на JS? Пробовал следующие, не помогло:

```
$('input').each (function () {
     $(this).val().replace('/#/g', '');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение возвращённое `replace` нужно чему-то присвоить, это не объект

```
$('input').each (function (key,obj) {
     obj.value=obj.value.replace(/#/g, '');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, решено.

Comment: зачем же сразу минусовать, ну скопировал не глядя, так прокомментируйте

Comment: @минусатор: откомментируйте, плиз.

Comment: Ок. Поставил Вам плюс. Только вот за что меня минусовали?

Comment: и @Gedweb и @Lucky ставили минуса на ответы в этом треде

Answer (score 1):

Регулярные выражения в JavaScript ограничиваются двумя слэшами без всяких кавычек. Метод replace это нативный метод JavaScript. Он принимает первым аргументом или регулярное выражение или строку, которая автоматически конвертируется в регулярное выражение. То есть писать нужно так:

```
$('input').each (function () {
     var replaced = $(this).val().replace(/#/g, '');
     console.log(replaced);
});
```

Или

```
$('input').each (function () {
     var replaced = $(this).val().replace('#', '');
     console.log(replaced);
});
```

Но второй вариант заменит только первое вхождение символа # в строке.

Comment: нужно как-то более корректно возмущаться, минус убрал

Answer (score 0):

как вам такой вариант:

```
$('input').val(function(i, val) {
   return val.replace('/#/g', '');
});
```

- [.val( function(index, value) )](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: кавычки только убрать, а так нарядно.